# Move rows of a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

my task is to shift the rows of an array by a fixed amount "shift" and fill the shifted rows with zeroes:

For example, the Array:

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 3 1 1

1 6 2 1 4

1 1 1 8 1

1 1 1 1 1

shifted by 2 should result in:

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 3 1 1

1 6 2 1 4

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] a = { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 3, 1, 1 }, { 1, 6, 2, 1, 4 }, { 1, 1, 1, 8, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, } };

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(move(a, 2)));

    }
public static int[][] move(int[][] a, int shift) {

        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= shift; i--) {
            a[i] = a[i - shift];

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }

        return a;
    }
```

My output is:
`[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 6, 2, 1, 4]]`

If i print my Array after the first for-loop it is correct, i do not understand why the 2nd for-loop changes rows 2 and 3.

Comment: In your first for loop you're assigning references to those rows, not copying the data in them. This means that when you assign values, the rows are looking at the same places, so "both" see 0.

Comment: For problems like this, it might help you to write down the answers in plain words (or pseudocode) then code the solution based on that. Also, you might try to come up with a array copy solution first. Create a new array filled with zeros, then copy each row of the original array from index 0 to the new array, starting at the offset (i.e. +2) until you can't copy no more rows. Then, once you have that solution working, create an "in-place" solution, where you overwrite the rows. Typically, the second approach tends to be more complex than the first. So when learning, this approach should help.

Comment: If you want to avoid referencing an entire row and causing this issue, you can copy the individual items in each row, going column by column instead with a nested for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy a row from one position to another, **you are copying a reference to the same row in memory** (*[check this out](https://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java#:%7E:text=Cloning%20an%20Array%20in%20Java)*). You should consider this to your code run properly:

```java
public static int[][] move(int[][] a, int shift) {
    int rows = a.length;
    int cols = a[0].length;
    
    // New array to store the result
    int[][] result = new int[rows][cols];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - shift; i++) {
        // Copy the rows
        result[i + shift] = a[i].clone();
    }

    // Loop it
    for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            // Fill with zeros
            result[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it must be confusing at first, this weird behavior is due to pointers. When changing the values of the rows for your `shift` function, you have changed the reference types of the third and fourth rows to be the first and second rows.

The problem is in the first loop. As a consequence, any change done to the first row is also mirrored in the third row. Same regarding the second row, fourth. You have linked them together.

That's why it changed them as well is the second loop.

I would advice you to change each of the row's values instead of the reference types, as such:

```
for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= shift; i--) {
        
    for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
        a[i][j] = a[i - shift][j];
    }
        
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, "I would advice you to change each of the row's values instead of the reference types, as such:"  I do understand what you mean but how do i do that? I do understand the issue with the reference, but how do i tell Java to change the value instead of just the reference?

Comment: you can't, what you are trying to change is a pointer, and you gave it a new address. The only value a pointer can hold is a reference to another object, so your only viable options are to either give it a clone (the other answer), or you can copy the stuff by value (my ans).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  Note that you can do it without creating a new array to store the result.  (i.e. you can do an in place shift).

The key point to note is you are copying references in the array.  When you shift the arrays, from left to right, there is no problem.  But you can't just fill the existing rows with zeroes since you would be overwriting previously copied array objects and they would be altered.

Also, the smaller the shift value is the more copying is required.  The exception to this is a value of `0` where you just return the given array.

```
int[][] a = {{1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,3,1,1},{1,6,2,1,4},{1,1,1,8,1},
         {1,1,1,1,1}};

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(move(a, 2)));
```

prints

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1], [1, 6, 2, 1, 4]]
```

- First, check for valid arguments:

  - throw an exception if the shift is out of bounds.
  - If the array is `null`, `empty` or the shift value is `0`, just return the original array.
- Otherwise, create a new array of zeroes for insertion into vacated cells.
- Now iterate in over the array, in reverse from the `last cell index` to the `shift value`, copying the appropriate **array references** as you go.
- once finished, simply copy a `clone` of the zero array into the vacated cells using `shift` as `index` and decrement accordingly.

```
public static int[][] move(int[][] a, int shift) {
  
   // handle special cases
   if (shift > a.length || shift < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Shift value(%d) out of range for array"
                            .formatted(a.length));
   }
   
   if (a == null || a.length == 0 || shift == 0) {
       return a;
   }
   
   // create zero array replacement
   int[] zeros = new int[a[0].length];
   Arrays.fill(zeros, 0);
   
   // copy the references
   for (int i = a.length-1; i >= shift; i--) {
       a[i] = a[i-shift];
   }
   // fill the "vacated" cells.
   while(shift-- > 0) {
       a[shift] = zeros.clone(); 
   }
   return a;
}
```